# Maven POM multi environment profiels

Tags: java, maven

This is the `<build>` tag from my old POM that was working:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
    </build>
```

Now i want to have 3 different api.properties files for every stage: prod, dev, test. So i went ahead and followed the `<profile>` tutorials for maven. This is what i ended up with for just the prod and test stage (completely removing the old `<build>` tag):

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                            <tasks>
                                <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/api.prod.properties" />
                                <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/api.dev.properties" />
                                <copy file="src/main/resources/api.test.properties"
                                    tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/api.properties" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                            <tasks>
                                <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/api.test.properties" />
                                <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/api.dev.properties" />
                                <copy file="src/main/resources/api.prod.properties"
                                    tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/api.properties" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <finalName>test</finalName>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

That doesn't really work however. Will generate just one .war and not the 3 wars i want (test-prod.war, test-dev.war, ...) and the generated war will contain all 3 .properties files instead of the one it should have. Why and what can i do to fix it? I am pretty new to maven... Thanks!

Comment: how do you run the maven build? With all three profiles selected? Running them once for each profile should deliver you the three different artifacts.

Comment: @Abaddon666: I just run maven install in my eclipse, as usual... How do i run it "different" ?

Comment: i am usually running maven builds from command line which would then look like e.g. `mvn clean install -Ptest` for running the test profile. Otherwise you have to google how profiles can be selected for the maven plugin you are using

Comment: First you should use uptodate Maven plugins.. Maven Compiler Plugin Version 2.0 is really ancient. Current Version is 3.5.1. Furthermore I don't know where you have found to configure tasks within the configuration for maven-compiler-plugin...means...remove it....

Comment: Based on your requirement to build different wars for different environments the usage of profiles is the wrong way. Better use things like this https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

use

```
mvn clean compile -P prod,dev,test
```

also it's better to have the build tag outside your profile tag and reference the properties of the profile inside your plugins. e.g. you can specify the folder for the properties in your profile and then reference this property anywhere else.

```
   <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <properties.dir>YOUR_DEV_DIR</properties.dir>
        </properties>
   </profile>
```

then you can reference `${properties.dir}` anywhere else